# Heroine named Shelby stranded on a planet of telepaths

Tags: story-identification, novel

In the late 70's I read a good scifi book about a woman named Shelby who is the pilot of a space freighter. It has a problem and she sets down on a planet to wait for help. The planet is peopled with near-humans named "shades" who are telepathic and live separately except for a time once a year when they mate. She gets caught up in it, and loses awareness, then is later rescued by a passing starship.

I liked the story but long ago forgot the title and author. Suggested the name Shelby to my brother, who named his daughter that. I would like to tell her about the book. Thank you!

Comment: Is there some way to search for this kind of thing? Google did not turn it up. Is there a database of books? I can't believe that I am the only person who read this book.

Comment: Your very best bet is to try to remember more info; What was the freighter's problem? What was the name of her ship? What was the name of the planet? What was the name of the ship that rescued her? Can you remember any of the characters? Can you remember any part of the name of the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That novel is called *[Last Communion](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0451098226)*

> Boomerang--an untouched pastoral planet: on the surface it seems a perfect candidate for human colonization. But first a Colcom survey team must make contact with the Sades-=the humanoid-looking natives of Boomerang--and determine whether they are animals or intelligent beings. However, the Sades appear to have no interest in the survey team. Mot, at least, until the day that pilot Shelby Michaels encounters a mortally wounded Shade. Then, in a totally unexpected way, contact is finally established, and for Shelby there is not going back.

Comment: Can you please give some information as to why you think this.  Not just a link.

Comment: It does involve a "Shelby" although the aliens seem to be named "Sades". I have yet to find a better summary.

Comment: Pilot named Shelby, creatures Sades vs. Shades, I think it's too similar to be just a coincidence.

Comment: This looks correct, but I seem to recall reading it a few years before the 1981 publication date? No Accepted Answer button is showing, so I cannot choose this (only) answer, but thank you very much. I wish I had seen this two days ago before I placed an Amazon order!

Comment: Yes, this is the right book, I really enjoyed re-reading it. I will give it to my niece now.